# Determine if user removed from third party organisation's Azure Active Directory tenancy is invalid

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

We have an application which is in our Azure AD tenancy, which we invite users from other Azure tenancies into our tenancy to use.

The user is invited into our tenancy with a guest invitation via B2B.  One accepted, a user record is added to our tenancy with a user type of Guest Account, and source of External Azure Active Directory.  The user can access the application.

However, we want to ensure that a user that is removed from the third party tenancy is actually invalid.  We have tried to do a check on the user in our tenancy (via Graph API), but this does not seem to work, as the guest user account is still in our tenancy.  Access reviews ( as suggested in https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/33709639-remove-b2b-user-when-host-account-is-removed) are a possible solution, but this does seem to involve some degree of manual process.

Is there another way in which we can determine if the user is invalid if the user has been removed from the third party organisation's tenancy?

Answer (score 0):

Since this idea has been published on [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/33709639-remove-b2b-user-when-host-account-is-removed), it means that Microsoft has not yet introduced a method to automatically identify the guest user that has been removed. Otherwise, Microsoft engineers will post a statement in the UserVoice.

Currently it's strongly recommended that you refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/governance/manage-guest-access-with-access-reviews) as a workaround to achieve your goals.